Nginx ssl_verify_client and proxy_pass at the same time?
Is it a problem to use nginx with the options ssl_verify_client and proxy_pass both enabled at the same time?
The first server (LB) is nginx, the 2nd server (web) is node.js.
I am getting a 502 bad gateway, and the request does not reach the 2nd server at all - nothing in its request logs.
Without ssl_verify_client the response is 200 OK.
The client cert is correct: response headers include X-ssl_client_verify: SUCCESS so it must be something else causing the 502.
Logically it sounds like it is the combination of the two options.  If ssl_client_verify returns SUCCESS, but the request is not sent onwards to the server until the option is removed, then that indicates that the two options are not compatible?
There are 2 conf files in use:
default.conf:
upstream app_servers {
  least_conn;
  server web:80;
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;

  server_name _;

  # production
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;

  # support mutual 2 way ssl
  ssl_verify_client on;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/client/client.bundle.pem
  ssl_verify_depth 10;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
  client_max_body_size 5m;
}

example.com.conf:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443;

server_name example.com;

location / {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://app_servers;
  
  # uncomment if any errors need tracing
  error_log traffic/err.log debug;

  # check the result of ssl client cert verify
  add_header X-ssl_client_verify $ssl_client_verify always;
  if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") {
    return 403;
  }

  proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginxX-Proxy true;

  proxy_set_header X-client-cert-verifiy $ssl_client_verify;
  proxy_set_header X-sni $ssl_server_name;
  proxy_set_header X-client-cert $ssl_client_raw_cert;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
}
}

I have been using nginx as a LB with proxy_pass on other related sites for years without any problems.

Why do you split the SSL server block in two? In any way, there is only one server block responsible to handle the request, and every nginx variable, i.e. $ssl_client_verify, has its particular value only within the request context.

Not 100% sure, I inherited it like this on our oldest sites and every site since has been done like this because it works.  The first block is the LB rules - eg handle ssl, and the 2nd block is the websites rules

Unfortunatelly I'm not an expert with the LB; however, maybe you can add an additional HTTP header to pass the result of the client certificate verify result?

Add the header to what sorry?  You can see I already have add_header X-ssl_client_verify to add it to the response and also proxy_set_header X-client-cert-verifiy $ssl_client_verify to send it from the LB to the web

add_header directive is for the response and should not affect this issue. Do I understand correctly that the first nginx config is for LB, the second one is for the app?
